# Issue with returning an equation in Java

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with my function call. I'm trying to find the solution to the two-point boundary value problem x' = f(t,x) = x + 0.09 x 2 + cos(10 t) with boundary condition x(0) + x(1) - 3.0 = 0  using the secant and third-order Runge-Kutta methods and for whatever reason, my equation method gives me four errors on a single line, those being that it's not a statement, is missing two semicolons, and is missing an end parenthesis.

```
public class BoundaryValueProblem 
{
    public static double f(double t, double x) 
    {
        return x + 0.09x^2 + Math.cos(10t);
    }

    public static void findZero
    {
        double x4; 
        double x5 = .7; 
        double x6 = 1.0;
        int n = 1; 
        double fx; 
        double f1;
        double f2; 
        double Error;
        BoundaryValueProblem FZ = new BoundaryValueProblem();
        f1 = FZ.f(1.0, 1.0);
        f2 = FZ.f(1.0, 1.0);
        System.out.println("Secant Method");
        System.out.println("n: \t\t x1: \t\t x2: \t\t Error:");
        while(abs(x5 + x6 - 3.0) < 1e-5)
        {
            x4 = x6 - f2 * ((x6 - x5)/(f2 - f1));         
            fx = FZ.f(1.0, 1.0);
            x5 = x6;
            x6 = x4;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = fx;         
            Error = x5 + x6 - 3.0;              
            System.out.println(n + "\t\t" + x5 + "\t\t" + x6 + "\t\t" + Error);
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void rkm(double x0, double t0, double h)
    {
        double x1, x2, x3;
        int i=0;
        double a1 = 0.5;
        double a2 = 0.25;
        double c0 = 2.0/3.0;
        double c1 = 5.0/3.0;
        double c2 = -4.0/3.0;
        double b21 = -.25;
        double b10 = .5;
        double b20 = .5;   
        double stepsize = .025;
        System.out.println("Runge-Kutta Method:");
        System.out.println("i: \t\t h: \t\t t0: \t\t x0:");
        System.out.println(i + "\t\t " + h + "\t\t " + t0 + "\t\t " + x0 );  
        for(i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {            
            x1 = x0 + h * b10 * f(t0, x0);
            x2 = x0 + h * (b20 * f(t0, x0) + b21 * f(t0 + a1 * h, x1));
            x3 = x0 + h * (c0 * f(t0, x0) + c1 * f(t0 + a1 * h, x1) + c2 * f(t0 + a2 * h, x2));           
            t0 = t0 + stepsize;  
            x0 = x3;
            System.out.println(i + "\t\t " + h + "\t\t " + t0 + "\t\t " + x0 );   
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BoundaryValueProblem FZ1 = new BoundaryValueProblem();
        FZ1.findZero();
        BoundaryValueProblem RKM1 = new BoundaryValueProblem();
        RKM1.rkm(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }     
}
```

I've had it work on simpler equations but this one is not working for me. I have the rest of the code mostly correct (I believe), but I don't think it's the cause of the error since I commented it out and the errors persisted, thus I'm not focused on that. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you point out which specific lines or statements have compile errors to help people look in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Below is fixed code. Please remember that java unlike Octave or Matlab requires multiplication operator (`*`) and doesn't support pow operator (`^`) - you would need to use `Math.pow()` instead.

```
public class BoundaryValueProblem {
    public static double f(double t, double x) {
        return x + 0.09 * x * x + Math.cos(10 * t);
    }

    public static void findZero() {
        double x4;
        double x5 = .7;
        double x6 = 1.0;
        int n = 1;
        double fx;
        double f1;
        double f2;
        double Error;
        f1 = f(1.0, 1.0);
        f2 = f(1.0, 1.0);
        System.out.println("Secant Method");
        System.out.println("n: \t\t x1: \t\t x2: \t\t Error:");
        while (Math.abs(x5 + x6 - 3.0) < 1e-5) {
            x4 = x6 - f2 * ((x6 - x5) / (f2 - f1));
            fx = f(1.0, 1.0);
            x5 = x6;
            x6 = x4;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = fx;
            Error = x5 + x6 - 3.0;
            System.out.println(n + "\t\t" + x5 + "\t\t" + x6 + "\t\t" + Error);
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void rkm(double x0, double t0, double h) {
        double x1, x2, x3;
        int i = 0;
        double a1 = 0.5;
        double a2 = 0.25;
        double c0 = 2.0 / 3.0;
        double c1 = 5.0 / 3.0;
        double c2 = -4.0 / 3.0;
        double b21 = -.25;
        double b10 = .5;
        double b20 = .5;
        double stepsize = .025;
        System.out.println("Runge-Kutta Method:");
        System.out.println("i: \t\t h: \t\t t0: \t\t x0:");
        System.out.println(i + "\t\t " + h + "\t\t " + t0 + "\t\t " + x0);
        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            x1 = x0 + h * b10 * f(t0, x0);
            x2 = x0 + h * (b20 * f(t0, x0) + b21 * f(t0 + a1 * h, x1));
            x3 = x0 + h * (c0 * f(t0, x0) + c1 * f(t0 + a1 * h, x1) + c2 * f(t0 + a2 * h, x2));
            t0 = t0 + stepsize;
            x0 = x3;
            System.out.println(i + "\t\t " + h + "\t\t " + t0 + "\t\t " + x0);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoundaryValueProblem FZ1 = new BoundaryValueProblem();
        FZ1.findZero();
        BoundaryValueProblem RKM1 = new BoundaryValueProblem();
        RKM1.rkm(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method without parentheses: `public static void findZero`

It should be `public static void findZero()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void findZero// correct this. Where are parenthesis () for this method
{
    double x4; 
    double x5 = .7; 
    double x6 = 1.0;
    int n = 1; 
    double fx; 
    double f1;
    double f2; 
    double Error;
    BoundaryValueProblem FZ = new BoundaryValueProblem();
    f1 = FZ.f(1.0, 1.0);
    f2 = FZ.f(1.0, 1.0);
    System.out.println("Secant Method");
    System.out.println("n: \t\t x1: \t\t x2: \t\t Error:");
    while(abs(x5 + x6 - 3.0) < 1e-5)
    {
        x4 = x6 - f2 * ((x6 - x5)/(f2 - f1));         
        fx = FZ.f(1.0, 1.0);
        x5 = x6;
        x6 = x4;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = fx;         
        Error = x5 + x6 - 3.0;              
        System.out.println(n + "\t\t" + x5 + "\t\t" + x6 + "\t\t" + Error);
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Function findZero should have parenthesis at the end like this:
   **public static void findZero()**
2. **return x + 0.09x^2 + Math.cos(10t);**

In Java you have to put math operator between operands so instead of 0.09x you have to write 0.09*x and instead of 10t you have to write 10*t

^ sign is XOR operator not power operator so you have to use Math.pow function (I'm guessing that's what you wanted to do)

In the end this line should look like this:
**return x + Math.pow(0.09*x, 2) + Math.cos(10*t);**

3. I'm also getting error with abs function. I don't know if you wrote that function yourself but if you didn't you should use Math.abs function